# Opening Notes.app threw "kernel panic" like error and logged me out, now Finder will not load until reboot - macOS High Sierra 10.13.6

Tags: high-sierra, kernel-panic

I'm running macOS High Sierra 10.13.6 on my mid 2011 Mac Mini.

Very strange issue that just started yesterday. I *think* it happened when I opened Messages.app yesterday (got a warning about it crashing last time "do you want to open it?" today), but today it was Notes.app that caused the issue...

When I opened the app my left monitor went black and there was an error message that flashed across the screen (almost like a kernel panic), then I was at the login screen. Now I have logged back in but **Finder will not load**. Yesterday after rebooting everything was back to normal for awhile, but I can't have this happening in the middle of my work day. :(

With the issue happening, when I try to launch Finder from terminal I get this:

`MacMini:~ KidUsr$ open .`
`LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -54 for the file /Users/KidUsr.`
I also tried (from `~/`)...
`MacMini:~ KidUsr$ open Documents`
...but that failed with the exact same error.

Just like most of you, I'm working from home and this is my primary machine. So I'm in big trouble if I can't get this fixed ASAP. Are there some logs that can help me here? Much TIA.

**Update:** I found this bug report on GitHub which seems related since I'm indeed on macOS High Sierra and I have Python 3.6.1 installed, but I am not really sure...also I've had Python 3 installed for a long time, over a year at least: https://github.com/beeware/briefcase/issues/66